# Text node added but not visible in html

Tags: html, css

There is extra padding around my `<p>` tag that is visible in browser and email client when viewing however I cannot see it in the html. I do not want any padding above and below the `<p>` tag.
When I view the html in a browser and look at the source, I can see "" text node added but I cannot see them in the html therefore cannot remove them.
Can anyone help me remove this extra padding above/below `<p>` tag?

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="flexibleContainer" width="100%">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">
        <table bgcolor="f2f1ee" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="flexibleContainer" style="width:580px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;" width="580">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" class="narrowFlexibleContainerCell" style="width:580px;padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;" valign="top" width="580">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" class="narrowFlexibleContainerCell" style="width:560px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;" valign="top" width="560">
                                <table bgcolor="ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="left" class="textContent" valign="top"> 
                                            <p style="padding-right: 20px; padding-left: 20px;padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; margin: 0em "><Lorem Ipsum: </strong><br />
                                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam vulputate convallis risus sed sollicitudin. Suspendisse vel arcu vel erat dapibus tincidunt. Nunc quis orci imperdiet, lobortis quam at, mollis lacus. Aliquam mattis mi bibendum ultrices mattis. Fusce a felis lacinia felis elementum imperdiet.</p>
                                              </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <p style="font-size: 5px;"> </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: There is a `<br/>` before your text that is adding some space

Answer (score 0):

You have a `strong` tag which is not correctly open around the first part of your text:

```html
<Lorem Ipsum: </strong>
```

must be :

```html
<strong>Lorem Ipsum: </strong>
```

Comment: Thank you but even with the <strong> fixed, I still get this extra padding above and below the <p> tag

Answer (score 0):

Near the end, you have an empty paragraph with font-size set to 5px; i.e.

```
<p style="font-size: 5px;"> </p>
```

Try removing the margins around it, like this:

```
<p style="font-size: 5px; margin: 0;"> </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This `p`?

```
<p style="font-size: 5px;"> </p>
```

If so, unlike the other paragraph tags in your code, you do not have `margin: 0;` on that one.

Interesting thing is many HTML elements have default margin. The extra space is `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`, not padding. Setting the style to `margin: 0;` will eliminate this.

A handy list: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp

Comment: Glad that helped. Would you consider mine the accepted answer?